# Multiple tor exit nodes in python

Tags: python, tor

I'm developing an application that need to use different tor exit nodes. 
How can i create multiple connection through a SINGLE instance of tor??

I already found this but I found it's a little bit "dirty" (but definitely working solutions).
http://blog.databigbang.com/distributed-scraping-with-multiple-tor-circuits/

It's possible? Thank you!

Comment: What did you find "dirty" about it?

Comment: I found "dirty" to have multiple tor instance, without exploiting the possibility of having multiple circuit. 
It's possibile to find a solution using socksipy and ATTACHSTREAM?

Comment: Check the links below, hope can be helpful: 1. https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server#multiple_tor_processes 2. http://www.howtoforge.com/ultimate-security-proxy-with-tor (This one applies to Arch Linux)

Answer (score 1):

You can always generate "new identity".

Check this two questions:

1. [Get new Ip in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376987/get-new-ip-in-python)
2. [How to request new TOR identity in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal)

You can freeze the Exit node, but probably you can't freeze more than one.

In the other side, you can restrict the number of exit nodes, by enumeration in the *torrc*.

Comment: Wouldn't that need a lot of time to switch?