# Get new Ip in python

Tags: python, tor

I'm currently trying to get a new ip via python.

I found this script on stackoverflow:

```
import urllib2
from TorCtl import TorCtl

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 

def newId():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")

for i in range(0, 10):
    print "case "+str(i+1)
    newId()
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

I have my vidalia running and privoxy. I have my settings correctly set:

in system preference (on mac) :

Web Proxy (HTTP): 127.0.0.1:8118
and the same for HTTPS

In my privoxy config file I have this line:

```
 forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9051 .
```

and in my settings of vidalia I have:

[image]

Though still when I run the code it is stuck on on case 1 and I can't get an ip.
This is the log of my vidalia:

```
May 04 19:15:27.381 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:15:27.382 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:15:33.709 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:15:38.653 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:15:57.382 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:15:57.463 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:15:57.464 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:03.710 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:19.656 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:22.448 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:22.569 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:22.900 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:27.382 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:27.412 [Notice] New control connection opened.
May 04 19:16:27.413 [Notice] New control connection opened.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

edit:

When the line in the config file is active I can't load any site .

Apparently if I wait long enough I get an error:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Forwarding failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

not

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9051 .
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to come up pretty frequently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013707/how-can-i-change-my-tor-process-endpoint-in-stem), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal)) so I just added a [FAQ entry](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) for it. Tor does not support a method for cycling your IP but it does allow you to create a new identity. Please don't overdo this though, as it puts a high load on the Tor network.

[TorCtl is deprecated](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/torctl-deprecation-and-stem-plans), so here's an example using [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/)...

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```