# How to request new TOR identity in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, telnet, tor

I am trying to connect to TOR via telnet in my terminal on my mac osx and to request new identity, but it is not working, I always get this error message:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I am using this telnet command for the connection:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9051
```

And idea why is this not working?

thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change tor exit node programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-programmatically)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way to get "new identity" is send [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) signal.

Tor daemon re-read configurations files and make "new identity".

I keep special bash script for this:

```
# cat /usr/local/bin/nym 
#!/bin/bash
pidof tor | xargs sudo kill -HUP
```

My sudoers file full of NOPASSWD:

```
# cat /etc/sudoers 
....
anonymous       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
...
```

Try this.

Comment: Instead of `pidof tor | xargs sudo kill -HUP` why not just do `killall -HUP tor`?

Comment: @MathiasBynens I'm not the OP, but in some docker containers `killall` isn't installed

Answer (score 12):

Have you set a control port in your torrc? To make it available via telnet you will need "ControlPort 9051". After that you will want to give tor a NEWNYM signal...

```
$ telnet localhost 9051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
AUTHENTICATE
250 OK
SIGNAL NEWNYM
250 OK
```

You can do this via a script using [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) with...

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Thanks for the question! I've added it to [stem's faq](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor).

Comment: If you're using the Tor Browser Bundle you don't need to set a control port, it is already set to 9151.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu users, who have been kicked here by google search engine xD :

```
$ test your current IP
$ curl -sx socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 ifconfig.co | grep -oP '(?<=Your IP</span>: ).*(?=</span>)'
185.220.100.255

$ to get new NYM just restart TOR service
$ sudo service tor restart

$ but remember a new NYM is not always is a new IP, so check your IP again and redo step 2 if it is the same one
$ curl -sx socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 ifconfig.co | grep -oP '(?<=Your IP</span>: ).*(?=</span>)'
185.220.101.214
```